# from L1 to L2 (earth-sun system) using gravity assistance with the moon

Tags: orbit, lagrangian-points

I was wondering if it's possible, when we have a satellite in L1, or going to the L1 direction from the earth, to use a gravity assistance with the moon in order to go in L2.
I read that it's possible for a satellite going from the earth to the L1 point to be redirected to the L2 point with a cost of more or less 750m/s. If the gravity assist using the moon is feasible, do you think this cost is anyway the speed to add with thruster?

Thanks for your answer, and sorry if this question has already be asked, I read a lot of topic but I can't find the answer. The L1 and L2 point are the point of the earth-sun problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [*Wind*](http://wind.nasa.gov) spacecraft did just this back in 2002-2004 over a series of several orbits.  It used the moon to change its angular momentum, but it also used its [thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernier_thruster) during the maneuver.  So technically, it was not entirely a moon-assisted launch into the [$L_{2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#L2) point.  Several spacecraft, including *Wind*, have used the moon to help them get to the [$L_{1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#L1) point as well.